# how to speed up prim's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to optimize this following algorithm that determines a minimal spanning tree:

```
public void Prim(int sVertex)
{
    source = sVertex;

    boolean[] mstv = new boolean[maxSize];

    for (int j = 0; j < gSize; j++)
    {
        mstv[j] = false;
        edges[j] = source;
        edgeWeights[j] = weights[source][j];
    }

    mstv[source] = true;
    edgeWeights[source] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < gSize - 1; i++)
    {
        double minWeight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int startVertex = 0;
        int endVertex = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < gSize; j++)
            if (mstv[j])
                for (int k = 0; k < gSize; k++)
                    if (!mstv[k] && weights[j][k] < minWeight)
                    {
                        endVertex = k;
                        startVertex = j;
                        minWeight = weights[j][k];
                     }
        mstv[endVertex] = true;
        edges[endVertex] = startVertex;
        edgeWeights[endVertex] = minWeight;
    } //end for
} //end Prim
```

My friend said I could speed this up some more but I don't know how. Any thoughts?

Comment: Prim's algorithm is usually implemented with a priority queue to keep track of the minimum-weight edge.